# HY000/2003 error using mysqli to connect on localhost or 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp

I am writing a php page that connects to a database on WAMP.

I have the following code:

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// connect to database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password); //error line (1)
$sql = "USE xdbl0zz14_biodiversity"; 
$conn->query($sql); //error line (2)
```

The error line (1) gives the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

The error line (2) gives the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
```

but I assume that is a direct result of the error before.

I have looked at services.msc and the wampmysqld64 service is started.

Thank you in advance.

***EDIT***

The mysql logs show:

```
2016-04-05T12:05:50.193100Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from      2*3072 to 2*320 pages, LSN=2471251
2016-04-05T12:05:50.380111Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2016-04-05T12:05:51.310164Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=2471251
2016-04-12T11:10:57.423304Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 2  user: 'root'

2016-04-12T22:34:23.288955Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 2  user: 'root'
```

Comment: Is there anything in the MySQL logs indicating it failed to start up?

Comment: you didn't choose a database

Comment: @Fred-ii- Whilst it's a bit of an odd way of doing it, isn't that what `USE xdbl0zz14_biodiversity` should do?

Comment: Change `'127.0.0.1'` to `'localhost'` and see if it works.

Comment: @miken32 it now says "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)" instead

Comment: Well if you're seeing that on Windows, you have some configuration problems!

Answer (score 0):

Given the information my best guess would be that mysqld fails to start up due to some internal error, possibly due to some InnoDB data file corruption. If the data is valuable (e.g.there is no backup, or it takes too long to load), I would try to figure out what `mysqld` process is doing with the help of `strace` and `gdb` and then go from there.

Otherwise, I would shut down mysqld process (`kill -9` if stubborn), wipe out all InnoDB files in the MySQL data directory (usually `/var/lib/mysql`) plus all `.frm` files of existing InnoDB tables, and try restarting MySQL service normally, then load the database from backup.

Comment: I stopped both wamp services in services.msc and exited wamp. I then removed the files auto.cnf, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1, ibtmp1 and a .pid file. Is this what you mean - on restart of wamp all the files returned and the same errors were generated? cheers.

Comment: Yes, that was the correct procedure. Are you running Mysql client and server on the same host? If yes, it was rather strange that a Windows client would be looking for the socket in a Unix-style path (/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock) as observed in another comment.

Comment: Yes the php page and wamp server are both being run from the same machine, I agree it is a little strange.